# #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes error in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Error
SQL query:

### -- --------------------------------------------------------

### -- Table structure for table `i18n`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `i18n` (

 `id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `locale` VARCHAR( 6 ) NOT NULL ,
 `model` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `foreign_key` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
 `field` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `content` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `locale` (  `locale` ,  `model` ,  `foreign_key` ,  `field` ) ,
KEY  `model` (  `model(50)` ,  `foreign_key` ,  `field(50)` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

Comment: could you provide us more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
KEY  `model` (  `model(50)` ,  `foreign_key` ,  `field(50)` )
```

with

```
KEY  `model` (  `model` ,  `foreign_key` ,  `field` )
```

Then it works: [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/203dd/1)

The error you receive does not make sense for your code.

BTW do not name a column `foreign_key`. That is a totally undescriptive name.